# Find Per group a specific value in another Column if does not exist in that group delete that group

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am having a trouble in deleting some records from a dataframe. If i groupby a certain column and check for each this column group in another column that for each group does it have any specific value in another column if that specific value does not exist delete that whole group from first column (The column upon which we have applied group by earlier). My data look like this:

| **search_value_per_group** | **Column_to_Be_Grouped** |
| --- | --- |
| Pakistan | Ehsan |
| Saudi Arab | Irshad |
| Pakistan | Ayesha |
| India | Ehsan |
| Switzerland | Ehsan |
| Nigeria | Ehsan |
| Saudi Arabia | Ayesha |
| UK | Ayesha |
| Pakistan | Zohan |
| Afghanistan | Zohan |
| Iraq | Zohan |
| Iran | Zohan |
| USA | Zohan |
| Netherland | Irshad |
| Switzerland | Irshad |
| India | Irshad |

I want to delete all that whole group which do not have **Pakistan** in that group. For example in my dataframe i will Delete All **Irshad** from  **Column_to_Be_Grouped** because in all irshad i do not have **Pakistan** and my desired output will look like this as follows:

| **search_value_per_group** | **Column_to_Be_Grouped** |
| --- | --- |
| Pakistan | Ehsan |
| Pakistan | Ayesha |
| India | Ehsan |
| Switzerland | Ehsan |
| Nigeria | Ehsan |
| Saudi Arabia | Ayesha |
| UK | Ayesha |
| Pakistan | Zohan |
| Afghanistan | Zohan |
| Iraq | Zohan |
| Iran | Zohan |
| USA | Zohan |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all matched groups and filter them by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
groups = df.loc[df['search_value_per_group'].eq('Pakistan'),'Column_to_Be_Grouped']
df1 = df[df['Column_to_Be_Grouped'].isin(groups)]

print (df1)
   search_value_per_group Column_to_Be_Grouped
0                Pakistan                Ehsan
2                Pakistan               Ayesha
3                   India                Ehsan
4             Switzerland                Ehsan
5                 Nigeria                Ehsan
6            Saudi Arabia               Ayesha
7                      UK               Ayesha
8                Pakistan                Zohan
9             Afghanistan                Zohan
10                   Iraq                Zohan
11                   Iran                Zohan
12                    USA                Zohan
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform('any')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to generate a boolean Series for [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df['search_value_per_group'].eq('Pakistan')
         .groupby(df['Column_to_Be_Grouped']).transform('any')]
```

output:

```
   search_value_per_group Column_to_Be_Grouped
0                Pakistan                Ehsan
2                Pakistan               Ayesha
3                   India                Ehsan
4             Switzerland                Ehsan
5                 Nigeria                Ehsan
6            Saudi Arabia               Ayesha
7                      UK               Ayesha
8                Pakistan                Zohan
9             Afghanistan                Zohan
10                   Iraq                Zohan
11                   Iran                Zohan
12                    USA                Zohan
```